# What's wrong in this simple android Program, I get 'Force Close'

Tags: android

What is wrong in this program, My eclipse IDE doesn't show any errors....when I execute this simple program the emulator shows force close....Anybody please clarify

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;

public class HelloWorld extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    View Et1,Bt1,TxtDisp;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.name_getter);
        Bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
        Et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.UserInput);
        TxtDisp=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextDisp);
        Bt1.setOnClickListener(this);      
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String userInput=((EditText) Et1).getText().toString();
        ((TextView)TxtDisp).setText(userInput);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the activity to the Android Manifest File (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)?

Comment: please, go to Logcat and try to find the stacktrace it will be really helpful here.

Comment: Eclipse does show errors... You just have to know where to see.  http://lampcms.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-get-logcat-view-pane-in-eclipse.html

Comment: I think there is nothing to add in the Manifest file. The activity is default activity and it is automatically added in the Manifest.xml. What I did is instead of using main.xml layout I used name_getter.xml layout. Does this have to do anything with this problem.

Comment: Tested your app on my device and SDK emulator and it worked fine. How is your name_getter.xml looking?

Comment: This is resolved....the mistake was in name_getter.xml....I did not specify android:layout_height="wrap_content" for EditText. This messed the code..Thanks a lot every body for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post your main.xml here. Something must have gone wrong there. Check whether you have assigned correct names for each view under `android:id` in  your layout

My guess is there should be a null pointer thrown at this line

```
Bt1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Can you check whether Bt1 is null? if yes your object has not been initialized properly.

Comment: Ya, the problem was in XML. I didn't declare android:layout_height="wrap Content" for EditText. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you know how to enable logcat?

please enable logcat and show us the exact exception it is throwing.

in eclipse, it is: `Window>Show View>Other>Android>Logcat`

Comment: Any resources about logcat will be greatfull

Comment: Are you using logcat already?? its a tool for Android developers which prints many things happening with the device/emulator. you can also use it to display your own messages, which will be used for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Without an error this is really hard,

- Have you declared your activity in the manifest?
- Does that contentview "name_getter" contain the ids Btn1, UserInput and TextDisp?
- Are those id's indeed respectively a Button, an EditText and a Textview?

Does the error start after clicking the button? Could it be that your getText returns null?

If you really can't get the logcat to work, at least add a bunch of try-catches to your code. If it executes you're getting an error in this file, and not somewhere else. You coudl also try to debug with debugmessages using a Toast.

(something like this, just guessing, you should look it up)

```
Toast t = Toast.maketext(this, "your error", Toast.LOOKTHISUP);
t.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me once.

Are you sure that

```
R.id.Btn1 is Button
R.id.UserInput is EditText
R.id.TextDisp is TextView
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do this:

public void onClick(View V)
{
switch(v.getId(){
case R.id.Bt1:
// do here what you want to do
break;
}
}